# Prevent multiple active batch spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark job with stream context running each 60seconds. The problem is that the processing time of one batch is too long (due to calculation and saving RDD and Parquet to Cloud Storage), one batch couldn't be able to finish within 1 minute timeframe. It ends up that next batch keep going in and become active (status = processing). After a while, I have 10 active batch in processing while the first one has been finished yet. As a result, it slowed down significantly and no batch is able to finish. Is there anyway to strictly limit the number of active batch to 1 at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: If you increase the batch interval, how long does a single take to complete?

Comment: How are you processing the data? Could you add the code? Spark Streaming, by default, only processes one batch at the time.

Comment: I'm having this same issue - I'm running a whole bunch of dstreams on the same cluster though. Maybe not enough cores? And while I agree with you @maasg, I'm also seeing multiple Active Batch[es].

Comment: @maasg
How can i make multiple batches to work in parallel, All batches have independent data. We need that each batch work in parallel . Any idea ?

Comment: @Imran you should ask a new question with your context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084775/spark-streaming-micro-batches-making-big-queues
@maasg please advise

Answer (score 0):

you can disable back pressure using the property 
spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true . This will ensure subsequent batches are in queued state and only 1 active batch running currently.